# "The device is not ready" when writing or reading files

Tags: c#, .net

When I tried opening a file, there is always an exception "System.IO.IOException: 'The device is not ready." showing up:

```
// reading
var data = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\test.txt");

// writing
File.WriteAllText(@"D:\test.txt", "");
```

My stack trace doesn't give any meaningful message:

> System.IO.IOException occurred 
>         HResult=0x80070015
>         Message=The device is not ready.
>
> Source=mscorlib
>         StackTrace:
>          at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>          at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>          at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>          at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
>          at System.IO.File.InternalReadAllText(String path, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)
>          at System.IO.File.ReadAllText(String path)
>          at [..].Main(String[] args) in [..]\Program.cs:line [..]

Comment: is `D:\\` a CD- of DVD drive? or is it your hard disc?

Comment: Can you read the same file in something like notepad?

Comment: Try read file from another path - probably you trying read from disc which is not plug-in yet.

Comment: @MongZhu "D:\" is my local disk.

Comment: its not a usb disk?

Comment: This one is Windows app/ Web?

Comment: @A3006 This is a .net 4.6.1 console program.

Comment: It worked as-is in my console app. So seems a local issue.

Comment: Most likely a hardware issue. But try running the app as admin.

Comment: Try running this  DriveInfo.GetDrives().All((d) => { Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1},{2},{3}", d.Name, d.IsReady,d.DriveFormat,d.DriveType); return true; }); Just to see what you will get